# Return a Column as string based on a other column set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table Structure

```
SNO     StudenNumber    Subject N0  Remark
 1      10                1     Good
 2      10                2     Average
 3      10                3     Very Good
 4      10                4     Poor
 5      10                5     Very Poor
 6      10                1     Very Good
 7      10                2     Good
 8      10                3     Outstanding
 9      10                4     Poor
 10     10                5     Very Poor
 11     10                1     Very Good
 12     10                2     Good
 13     10                3     Outstanding
 14     10                4     Good
 15     10                5     Poor
```

The following is the one particular student performance on a particular year on term 1, term 2, and term 3 exams.

Expected result is:

```
[1: Good, 2: Average, 3: Very Good, 4: Poor, 5: Very Poor],
[1: Very Good, 2 :  Good, 3: Outstanding 4 : Poor, 5:Very Poor],
[1: Very Good, 2 :  Good, 3: Outstanding 4 : Good, 5:Poor]
```

Comment: Please share table structure, sample data, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added table structure

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You realise SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported? You might want to consider upgrading ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **STRING_AGG** and **RowNumber** Function to attain this:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(M.SUBJECT_NO,' : ',M.REMARK),',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY M.S_NO) 
FROM @T M INNER JOIN (
SELECT S_NO,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBJECT_NO ORDER BY SUB_NO) AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM @T)S ON S.S_NO=M.S_NO
GROUP BY S.ROW_NUMBER
```

For SQL 2008:  You can achieve this using `Stuff`

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBJECT_N0 ORDER BY SUBJECT_N0) AS 
ROW_NUMBER ,REMARK,SUBJECT_N0 FROM @T )

SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT  CONCAT(',',T1.SUBJECT_N0,': ',REMARK)
FROM CTE T1
WHERE T1.ROW_NUMBER=CTE.ROW_NUMBER
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CONCATENATION FROM CTE
```

[image]

Comment: I am working on sql servre 2008. String_agg function is not supporting. thanks you for your response

Comment: I had edited the Code .Can u check and update ur comments --@Sathiamoorthy

Comment: Did u check this?  @Sathiamoorthy